# Recorrer JSON en JavaScript

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Se me presenta el siguiente escenario, tengo en mi `HTML` un `<textarea>` en el cual el usuario va ingresar una consulta, como si de la línea de comando se tratase, ejemplo, puedo ingresar:

> SELECT * FROM usuarios;
>
> SELECT * FROM paises;
>
> SELECT email, nickname, rango FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = 1;

Con una petición `AJAX` mando la consulta que quiera, esta me regresa un `JSON` que contiene los registros de la consulta.

Por ejemplo para la primera consulta de arriba el JSON generado es el siguiente:

http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1c469eec2dc1381345b18269ea9a6824

Y para la segunda consulta es el siguiente:

http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=80fda2c410a0f56520f14746729b25f8

¿Cómo puedo recorrer estos JSON? Obteniendo los encabezados y sus registros, para así generar una tabla `HTML` con los datos obtenidos.

Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo `JS` logro obtener los registros y crear las tablas, pero sin sus correspondientes encabezados.

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#realizarQuery').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var valorTextArea = $('#valorTextArea').val();
  $.ajax({
   url: 'realizarQuery.php',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: {valorTextArea},
  })
  .done(function(data) {
   console.log("success");
   console.log(data);
   console.log(typeof data);
   $.each(data, function(index, val) {
    if (val == '¡Escribe tu query!') {
     $('#texto').html('¡ESCRIBE TU QUERY!').css('font-size', '20px').css('color', '#D50000');
     $("#registrosIntermedios").html('').hide();
    }else if( val == '¡Verifique su sentencia SQL!'){
     $('#texto').html('¡VERIFIQUE SU SENTENCIA SQL!').css('font-size', '20px').css('color', '#D50000');
     $("#registrosIntermedios").html('').hide();
    }else{
      var tbl_body = "";
     var odd_even = false;
     $.each(data, function() {
         var tbl_row = "";
         $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
        })
        tbl_body += "<tr class=\""+( odd_even ? "odd" : "even")+"\">"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
        odd_even = !odd_even;               
     })

     $('#texto').html('LOS REGISTROS QUE CONTIENE SU CONSULTA SON LOS SIGUIENTES').css('font-size', '20px').css('color', '#2E7D32');
     $("#registrosIntermedios").html(tbl_body).show();
     
    }
  });
  })
  .fail(function() {
   console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
   console.log("complete");
  }, 'json');
  
 });
});
```

Por cualquier aportación, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En JS, en caso de que el resultado fue exitoso (tu `else`), entonces tu primero `each` va a recorrer las filas que se regresaron.
Usa una bandera para que en el primero renglón, recorras los campos del primer registro, usando los nombres del indice del arreglo (eso te creará tu encabezado, con los nombres de las columnas).
Luego ya puedes poner el siguiente renglon (recorres de nuevo esa primera fila del resultado), escribiendo ahora los valores...
En los subsecuentes, ya solo imprimes los valores.
Supongo que puedes usar una tabla para eso, poner los encabezados en `TH` y los datos en `TD`.

Espero se entienda mi 'pseudo-codigo', de no ser así, me dices y lo pongo más detallado.

También puedes consultar las respuestas a [Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery) , aunque esta en ingles, puedes ver que sugieren usar jqGrid, y otra respuesta tiene el código para hacerlo ahí mismo, similar a lo que describí arriba.

EDICIÓN:
Espero con los comentarios te quede más claro lo que esta haciendo. Quite lo referente a la "zebra" (alternar las clases para decorar los renglones).
También agregué para generar el encabezado de la tabla.

```
}else{
    var tbl_body = ""; // Iniciamos con una tabla vacía
    var tbl_row = ""; // para armar cada renglón

    // Encabezado de la tabla:
    // Recorremos el primer renglon, pero usamos los Key.
    // Los key, son los nombres de las columnas.
    $.each(data[0],function(k, v) {
        tbl_row += "<th>"+k+"</th>"; // Usamos TH, porque es el encabezado de la tabla
    }
    // Agregamos el encabezado a la tabla
    tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
    // termina bloque nuevo

    // Un ciclo para recorrer los renglones del resultado
    $.each(data, function() {
        tbl_row = ""; // Cada iteracion, vaciamos el renglón

        // Otro ciclo, para recorrer cada campo en el renglon actual
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            // Agregamos el campo al renglon.
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
        })

        // Agregamos el renglón a la tabla
        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
    })

    $('#texto').html('LOS REGISTROS QUE CONTIENE SU CONSULTA SON LOS SIGUIENTES').css('font-size', '20px');
    $("#registrosIntermedios").html(tbl_body).show();
}
```

Comment: Gracias me auxilié en el link que dejaste y funciona correctamente uno de los métodos que proporcionan, más sin embargo no logro entenderlo que es lo que importa XD

Comment: Tendría que ver el método que usaste, y podría explicártelo. Edita tu pregunta con el método que usaste.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Ahora lo edito.

Comment: Ahí lo edité @Octavio

Comment: una duda, es posible con lo hecho aquí, hacer que la tabla donde se vaciaron los registros, ¿sea paginada?, por ejemplo, que si las filas llegan a 15 se genere un botón o indice para ir a los siguientes 15 registros y así sucesivamente, dependiendo de los registros. Trate de buscar ejemplo y acoplarlos a este mismo código, pero no conseguí nada.

Comment: @antonio291093, podría ser posible, pero yo no te lo recomendaría. Una de las ventajas principales es reducir los datos en todos los sistemas involucrados. Por ejemplo, si tienes un query que devuelve 100,000 registros, la BD tiene que transmitirlos al servidor web, que luego tiene que transmitirlos al cliente, para que decida que solo va a mostrar 20 registros... mala idea.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. No lo había visto de esa manera jaja, salúdos.